# Operation could destabilize the runtime in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception, dll

I am using google analyics dll files in this project. it does not give any error at local but produces this error when io deploy website to server.

```
[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   Google.Apis.Discovery.BaseService.DeserializeResponse(IResponse input) in Service.cs:391
   Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.AnalyticsService.DeserializeResponse(IResponse response) in 0ixqzagp.0.cs:4340
   Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.FetchObject(IResponse response) in ServiceRequest.cs:203
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +241
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

in my code
i got this exception at this line

```
Profiles myProfiles = _service.Management.Profiles.List("~all", "~all").Fetch();
```

I have been searching on google for past 2 hours but could not get any solution. please provide solution. thanx in advance !!

Comment: Is codecoverage enabled?

Comment: what is codecoverage  and how to enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

This actually might be similar to the fix that I have put in about a month ago, which is in code review for the Google.Api.Services.BaseClientService.cs class.

Here's the bug report: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=330

Here's the code review with the patch: https://codereview.appspot.com/110190043/

Operation Could Destabilize Runtime Google.Api.Services.BaseClientService.cs

Essentially, I needed to run peverify against the DLL to figure out what syntax was causing a "possibility for destabilization". Once I found the line, I corrected the unsafe syntax that google had put in.

I also added a compiled version of the Google.Apis.dll, which includes the fix.

I hope this helps!